# angularjs directive template vs templateURL rendering timing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have a directive that loads an external HTML file as template using "templateURL". There is a function in the controller that relies on DOM to be fully rendered to execute correctly. The function throws an error because the expected DOM element is not ready when the function is called.

JS:

```
app.directive('directiveName',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div id="elmID"></div>',  //** THIS ONE WORKS **//
        templateURL:"template.html",        //** THIS ONE THROWS AN ERROR **//
        scope:false,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){},
        controller:function($scope){
            console.log(document.getElementById('elmID'));
        }
});
```

TEMPLATE: template.html

```
<div id="elmID"></div>
```

In reality my template.html file is pretty big, so I don't want to use inline code. Any one knows a work around?

Comment: `templateUrl`, not `templateURL`. It's case sensitive

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be doing DOM stuff in the controller. Do it in the `link` (postLink) function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is crashing because it's `templateUrl` not `templateURL`.

To answer your question about rendering/timing, read [this article](http://jasonmore.net/angular-js-directives-difference-controller-link/).

basically, the order goes:

1. compile
2. controller
3. pre-link
4. post-link (aka link)